# jqGrid 4.5.4 ASP.NET MVC3 Column Separator line showing/display away

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.5.4 for ASP.NET MVC application in which I have an issue with column separator.

First grid is the one I am using, when I am trying to expand the column using column separator at pkd column I see the separator line is showing away (in between create date column)as seen in image.

I am having this behavior across all the columns (Column Separator line displays away) through out the jqGrid

Second grid is from the demo in which I clicked  on CustomerID and I see the column separator exactly at the end of CustomerID column

[image: jqGrid Column Separator issue..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

გამარჯობა (Gamarjoba)! The version jqGrid 4.1.2 is a real retro version. If you *really* need to use the old version I would suggest you to modify `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` code. There are bug in the code of `dragStart` function (see [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L714-L721)). Some time before I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/529) which fix the bug. Now the code looks as the following (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L880-L889))

```js
dragStart: function(i,x,y) {
    var gridLeftPos = $(this.bDiv).offset().left;
    this.resizing = { idx: i, startX: x.clientX, sOL : x.clientX - gridLeftPos };
    this.hDiv.style.cursor = "col-resize";
    this.curGbox = $("#rs_m"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id),"#gbox_"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id));
    this.curGbox.css({display:"block",left:x.clientX-gridLeftPos,top:y[1],height:y[2]});
    $(ts).triggerHandler("jqGridResizeStart", [x, i]);
    if($.isFunction(p.resizeStart)) { p.resizeStart.call(ts,x,i); }
    document.onselectstart=function(){return false;};
},
```

I hope it will fix the problem which you have. Probably you will need make some other dependent changes (see [the code fragment](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L2171-L2175) and compare it with the code [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2629-L2633), see changes in [getOffset](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2388-L2395) and the usage of new [getColumnHeaderIndex](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2396-L2405)).

Comment: Sorry I am using jqGrid 4.5.4

Comment: In the case you should just apply [the changes](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/d7eb7f3deb265cf13e229c29f4f65aa2a8ebc60e) which I described in the pull request which I referenced. You can just try with [the file](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-dragStart.js) instead of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`.

Comment: I added dragStart function from the pull request by removing two lines and added three lines as given but still I have the issue. Will there be any sequence where I add the dragStart fucntion in my jqGrid code-- I am adding before afterInsertRow  after defining my columns... my jqGrid name is jqOrders  Code is added is below

Comment: dragStart: function(i,x,y) {
 var gridLeftPos = $(this.bDiv).offset().left;
 this.resizing = { idx: i, startX: x.clientX, sOL : x.clientX - gridLeftPos };
      this.hDiv.style.cursor = "col-resize";
      this.curGbox = $("#rs_m"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id),"#gbox_"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id));
this.curGbox.css({display:"block",left:x.clientX-gridLeftPos,top:y[1],height:y[2]});
      $(ts).triggerHandler("jqGridResizeStart", [x, i]);
      if($.isFunction(p.resizeStart)) { p.resizeStart.call(ts,x,i); }
      document.onselectstart=function(){return false;};
                },

Comment: @msbyuva: If the usage of [the fixed jquery.jqGrid.src.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-dragStart.js) instead of original `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` don't help you then you should provide the demo which reproduces your problem (but with my version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). I could debug the demo and will try to find the reason.

Comment: if I replace my original jquery.jqGrid.src.js with the fixed jquert.jqGrid.src it works fine but I am feared will that lead to any other issues as I am replacing original... I am just trying to plug the dragstart function in my razorview after defining the columns of jgGrid before other functions.... can't I use it in the view directly ?..

Comment: @msbyuva: You can compare (with respect of WinDiff.exe for example) the modified version of jquery.jqGrid.src.js with the original one. You will see that there are only 3 lines of differences which I described in my old pull request. So you should just replace `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` which you use to the fixed version. I don't understand your question about the usage of `dragstart` function in your razorview. You need just replace `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` in the whole project.

Comment: the fixed version of jquery.jqGrid.src.js -- is it official release  ? I have provide some documentation for my company to use it...

Comment: @msbyuva: Probably you don't use github. The main code of jqGrid will be published on github. Everybody can send pull request to the owner of the repository on github. I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/529) about 4 months before and **the pull request was merged**. So the main code of jqGrid was changed. So the next official release of jqGrid will definitively include my fix. By the way you can read [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/date-having-wrong-parsed-with-srcformat-iso8601long/#p30206) that the new release will be soon published.

Answer (score 0):

jqgrid use mouse x-postion to place the marker, in fact the marker's offset parent is the table wrapper, so just use the offset-x as x-place, u can see my overrided codes follow.

```
        dragStart: function(i,x,y) {
            //>>>override zhenyong
            // this.resizing = { idx: i, startX: x.clientX, sOL : x.clientX-6};
            this.resizing = { idx: i, startX: x.clientX, sOL : y[0]};
            //<<<override

            this.hDiv.style.cursor = "col-resize";
            this.curGbox = $("#rs_m"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id),"#gbox_"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id));
            //>>>override zhenyong
            // this.curGbox.css({display:"block",left:x.clientX-6,top:y[1],height:y[2]});
            this.curGbox.css({display:"block",left:y[0],top:y[1],height:y[2]});
            //<<<override
            $(ts).triggerHandler("jqGridResizeStart", [x, i]);
            if($.isFunction(p.resizeStart)) { p.resizeStart.call(ts,x,i); }
            document.onselectstart=function(){return false;};
        },
```